# Setting up a (web) development environment

Tags: php, netbeans, development-environment, virtualization

I would like to know how I can improve my development environment.

At the moment:

- I'm using Netbeans as my IDE.
- My local Dev server runs on a RHEL5 VirtualMachine similar to my production server.
- My Netbeans project is editing the VM files via ssh (I have mounted the server as a local drive)

But:

- It's slow
- Files can disapear ( netbeans delete them ? )
- I can't use git on it because it's slow.

The idea would be to be able to have a shared filesytem between the guest os and the host os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup sounds ok. You might need to give your virtual machine more resources however if your experiencing speed problems. That or move your server to a separate physical machine.

Comment: It only has 384mb at the moment. What would you advise?

Comment: (I'm only running a homecompiled php version and mysql)

Comment: Double it and see if it makes any difference. There may be other factors like cpu, i/o that could be affecting your server.
Also if your dev machine is win & your server is linux, samba could be slowing down the i/o

Comment: Did you have any luck getting your server to run faster?

Comment: yes its better with more ram, I don't really understand why tho :d

Answer (score 1):

You may try a setup for files the other way around. Keep your files an the host machine in the shared folder. Than on your VM create a symbolic link from your htdocs folder to that shared folder. In this case developing should be very fast but only running the website on your VM might be slower.

**EDIT**: My setup is the following:

- I got a XAMPP running on Windows 7 for development
- I got a SVN repository on the webserver the production system is runnig
- In a separate subdomain on my webserver I have a test system running

So basically I develop under Windows, I test on the same machine that runs my production system. We even got Macs for developing as well. I never had any issues developing under Windows and running the page on a openSUSE system (beside case-sensitive file names). Using the exact same machine for the test server is a good idea as it has the same limitations as the production server. So I think having three system DEVELOPMENT, TEST, PRODUCTION is the best you can get. But if it is only for some smaller projects your setup look quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I find XAMPP sufficient for nearly all development locally :)

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: I prefer using Vbox because the framework I'm using require to recompile php without all the core extentions. I also think it's better to stay close from the production env.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type Virtual Machine you're running. For example Vmware is able to share a specific folder between the guest and the host OS

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a mac, I'd recommend : http://www.mybringback.com/bringers/14509/git-local-and-shared-server-development-environment-with-ssh-setup/ 
which uses a local mamp/git/ and live server.

You could probably follow along with windows, but it's been awhile since I used it, so I'm 100%

best of luck